# AR.OLS isn't matching to an OLS on the autoregressive lags, Why?

Tags: regression, least-squares, autoregressive

I am using R and running ar.ols() on some data. And trying to compare to a more "manual" method of computing an AR model by doing lm() using the autoregressive lags as my independent variables. However the output I get is different. Can anyone explain why?

```
> demean
 [1]  0.3456 -0.2744 -0.3944  0.3056 -0.2144  0.0956  0.4156 -0.0744 -0.5744     -0.3444 -0.4344  0.4156  0.3656  0.3356 -0.1144 -0.4044  0.2656 -0.0444
[19] -0.1944  0.1356 -0.2544 -0.1444  0.4256  0.0256  0.3356
> a = demean[1:24]
> b = demean[2:25]
> ar_one = ar.ols(ts,order=1,demean = TRUE,aic = FALSE)
> ar_two = lm(a~b)
> ar_one

Call:
ar.ols(x = ts, aic = FALSE, order.max = 1, demean = TRUE)

Coefficients:
     1  
0.0549  

Intercept: -0.01363 (0.06308) 

Order selected 1  sigma^2 estimated as  0.0953
> ar_two

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)            b  
   -0.01319      0.05505  

> c = demean[1:23]
> d= demean[2:24]
> e=demean[3:25]
> ar_three = ar.ols(ts,order=2,demean=TRUE, aic=FALSE)
> ar_four = lm(c~d+e)
> ar_three

Call:
ar.ols(x = ts, aic = FALSE, order.max = 2, demean = TRUE)

Coefficients:
  1        2  
 0.1152  -0.2303  

Intercept: -0.003299 (0.06304) 

 Order selected 2  sigma^2 estimated as  0.09039
 > ar_four

Call:
lm(formula = c ~ d + e)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            d            e  
   -0.01418      0.07643     -0.24004
```

Comment: not only because of my answer: I vote to leave open because the question obviously arises due to issues with details of which regression is run, not so much due to issues with R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code allows me to get agreement between the two methods:

```
n <- 20
x <- rnorm(n)
ar.ols(x,order.max=1,demean=FALSE,aic=FALSE,intercept=TRUE)$ar
lm(x[2:n]~x[1:(n-1)])
```

By `demean=FALSE` I tell `ar.ols` not to demean the series prior to running the regression, `order.max=1` and `aic=FALSE` imply that only an AR(1)-model is fit and `intercept=TRUE` also fits a constant term like `lm`.

Your approach is more in the spirit of the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem, which says that a regression of $y$ on a constant and $X$ will have the same coefficient on $X$ as a regression of demeaned $y$ on demeaned $X$. Now, demean=TRUE apparently uses the same mean for both `x[2:n]` and `x[1:(n-1)]`, which leads to slight discrepancies. Indeed, the following produces identical results:

```
ar.ols(x,order.max=1,demean=TRUE,aic=FALSE,intercept=FALSE)$ar
xm <- x[2:n]-mean(x)
xml <- x[1:(n-1)]-mean(x)
lm(xm~xml-1)
```

Comment: I marked this answer correct because aside from it being accurate it also makes sense logically. 
However in my included example, I still cannot rectify the two methods to the same answer.
If you replace x with demean, which is my data [0.92 0.30 0.18 0.88 0.36 0.67 0.99 0.50 0.00 0.23 0.14 0.99 0.94 0.91 0.46 0.17 0.84 0.53 0.38 0.71 0.32 0.43 1.00 0.60 0.91] manually demeaned, you still get the slight discrepancy even though I am using the same mean for both "x[2:n] and x[1:n-1]"



---EDIT--
I actually discovered what was wrong. I was reversing my regression and making 
"x[2:n]" my ind var